# jsPDF addImage browser crash

Tags: jquery, html, jspdf, html2canvas

I am converting a list of divs into image using **html2canvas** and then adding them to a pdf in a new page using **addImage** and **addPage**. For smaller pdf everything works fine. The moment we reach pages more than 14, the browser crashes. Every page has a new image so the alias option available would not help me. I also have a background image and a footer for every page. For background and footer I use the alias:

```
doc.addImage(bgimgloaded,'JPEG',0,0,width,height,'mybgimg');
doc.addImage('mybgimg','JPEG',0,0,width,height);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the compression parameter with addImage.

https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/plugins/addimage.js#L520

You may need to test each compression option to see which one handles what you need: 'FAST', 'SLOW', 'MEDIUM', 'NONE'.

During the testing I've done with PDF's with a large amount of images, this has made a drastic difference. The memory still gets pretty high during the processing, but it does improve the speed and performance.